# Designing classes to help Junit Testing

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, refactoring, tdd

I will try to explain through pseudocode a code quality or design issue that I encountered while testing a spring boot application:

```
public class ControllerClass {
    controllerMethod(@RequestParam(version) String version) {

        service.generateFile(version)

    }
}

public class ServiceClass {

    private map = new HashMap<> ();

    void generateFile(version) {
        String rVersion = fetchRversion(version);
        String json = makeApiCall(url + rVersion);
        build(map);
        generateData(json)

    }
    generateData(json) {
        // uses map
    }
}
```

The above way of coding cause trouble when testing the generateData method.
So if I have the JSON, I pass it to the generateData function.
The trouble will be that map is built inside the `generateFile` function.
So it won't work. Either I built the map inside the test function for `generateData` or there could be some way of creating the Service class object with the map so that no testing function has to care about building or instantiating any other data. Since the version is passed at run time and based on that the map is built, will it be appropriate to have a separate build function inside the service class which can be called to setup all the required things?
Any alternative to this approach?

Comment: Do you always format your code like that?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thanks for pointing it out. I have formatted the code. Please let me know if it's still required to phrase my question in a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, it looks like a case of [sequential coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling). Consider a modified design of the class.

The simplest option is to add the required map as a method parameter to the `generateData` method:

```
generateData(json, map) {
    // uses map
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to solve this.

Another easy one would be to have another constructor for the ServiceClass that takes a Map as an argument:

```
// Poor names - I hope these are just examples.  Too generic; no information.
public class ServiceClass {

    private Map<X, Y> map;  // You don't use generics or declare properly.

    public ServiceClass() { this(null); }

    public ServiceClass(Map<X, Y> m) {
        // Never set a private variable equal to a mutable parameter.  You break encapsulation when you do.  Make a copy.
        this.map = (m != null) ? new HashMap<>(m) : new HashMap<>();
    }

    void generateFile(version) {
        String rVersion = fetchRversion(version);
        String json = makeApiCall(url + rVersion);
        // use this.map
        generateData(json)
    }

    void generateData(json) {
        // uses this.map
    }
}
```

Your JUnit test can instantiate the `Map` and pass it to the `ServiceClass` for the test.